# libev4 installation error

Tags: installation, apt

I get

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14 package 'python-pkg-resources':
file details field `Size' not allowed in status file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

when I'm trying to install `libev4`. I run

```
sudo apt-get install libev4
```

Please advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg exit with error parsing file \`/var/lib/dpkg/status\`, what to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343616/dpkg-exit-with-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-status-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dpkg` status file seems to be corrupted. However, as Ubuntu does automated backups of this file, you can restore it to a known good copy:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bak
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

If everything goes fine, you can then remove `/var/lib/dpkg/status.bak`.

Reference: [dpkg exit with error parsing file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, what to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343616/dpkg-exit-with-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-status-what-to-do)