# E:Error occurred while processing iw (NewVersion2)

Tags: 12.04

I have upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10. I am getting following error message

```
E:Problem parsing dependency Depends 
E:Error occurred while processing iw (NewVersion2) 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried the following command

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Ubuntu Software Center crashes with above error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Answer (score 6):

It seems like your `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file is corrupted. So try to replace the current status file with the old one.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bak
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: This worked for me, also another related answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343616/dpkg-exit-with-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-status-what-to-do